# BootstrapValidator, validate fields added dynamically to the form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I'm searching for a way to validate fields that I add to a form after the DOM is loaded and `$('#formId').bootstrapValidator()` is executed. Is there a way to add a new field and validate it when the form is submited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you couldn't use hidden fields when the form first loads and then validate them along with the other fields when the form is submitted?

Comment: I haven't way to know how many new fields will add, can be one or can be ten. So there's no way to know

Comment: I was picturing that the base form would load, then you would use maybe jQuery to add the hidden fields as required, then validate everything using Bootstrap validator. Rereading your question, maybe this isn't exactly what you are after though?

Comment: Yes. I add fields using jQuery, but there are not hidden, simply don't exists before. That's because the user can select add a simple input text or a input text with four textareas. This is because the fields are for make a survey, and the questions can have multi options or just an open question. The user can add as many questions as he want and this questions can be multi option or simple.

Comment: @Jairo , is there anything here that is helpful? http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/adding-dynamic-field/

Answer (score 6):

I was also searching same thing and found solution  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639287/bootstrapvalidator-how-do-you-add-and-remove-validators-dynamically-to-an-exist)

However in my case i have destroy bootstrap obj and reinitialize.

```
$('#sign-up_area').bootstrapValidator('destroy');
$('#sign-up_area').data('bootstrapValidator', null);
$('#sign-up_area').bootstrapValidator();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it solves the question.

Answer (score 2):

There's now a much easier way to accomplish this, using the `update` method of Bootstrap Validator:

```
$('#formId').validator('update')
```

From [the docs](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-methods):

> Updates the collection of inputs that will be validated. Call this method if the set of fields which need to be validated has changed.